# Electron/Photon Scattering

Tags: homework-and-exercises, scattering

Hey guys, 
I have a final tomorrow and I am going over some assignments. One of the questions from the assignment was:

> A photon having 37 keV scatters from a
>   free electron at rest. What is the
>   maximum energy that the electron can
>   obtain?

Now, I got the right answer (4.67 KeV) but I can't seem to figure it out now. Maybe I am just too tired. 
Any hints to where I should begin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only one parameter in the system. You have several choices, but you might use the scattering angle, $\Theta$, of the photon in the electrons initial rest frame.

Now conserve 4-momentum, and write the final state energy of the electron as a function of $\Theta$ and maximize.